# Number 9 in Hindu mythology

Tags: symbolism, numerology

What is the significance of Number 9 in Hindu mythology?

Even that every important numbers when summed up ends to a number 9.

*Example#1*: the life span of four yugas from this [link](http://www.stephen-knapp.com/timings_of_the_four_yugas.htm)

- Krita or Satya-yuga is 1,440,000 human years (*sum of digits is **9***)
- Treta-yuga is 1,080,000 human years (*sum of digits is **9***)
- Dvapara-yuga is 720,000 human years (*sum of digits is **9***)
- Kali-yuga is 360,000 human years (*sum of digits is **9***)

*Example#2*: "Nava grahas" - Nine planets in Hindu mythology.

*Example#3*: Navratri - lasts nine days.

*Example#4*: There are 9 Purans, 108 MahaPuran (Upnishads).Mahabharat has 18 chapters (batter lasted for 18 days), Geeta has 18 chapters, Bhagavat has 108000 Shloks (verses)

Links to refer:

- [Significance of 9?](http://www.hindunet.org/srh_home/1996_2/msg00272.html)
- [Myths-Dreams-Symbols](http://www.mythsdreamssymbols.com/nine.html)

***PS**: There might be some nonsense in the above reference links but they are just only to support my question.*

Comment: Interesting question...never took interest in our own religion until this site came live...

Comment: I have a very very very strong feeling this thing is completely baseless and (if) popularized, due to people of similar kind who made people believe that you should not cut nails on Saturday and other crap...

Comment: The reason that all of those numbers you quoted have a digit-sum of nine is more to do with the divisibility rules for 9 than with anything else (sum of digits congruent to 0 mod 9 → divisible by 9). I don't know what you're talking about with "heart beats per minute" (do you realize this is not a fixed number and varies from person to person?), but that cannot possibly be related.

Comment: I completely agree with @senshin. It would have been more reasonable if you asked why we add '1' to every _gurudakshina_ and other pays... Like 11, 51, 101 and rest.

Comment: I just can't find source online. but I will update it once I reach home and get the details about the book.

Comment: @senshin I updated with a link. which tells exactly what I am trying to say here. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green Look, the real question here is _why is 108 significant?_, and there may be a good answer for that (honestly, I think it's just because 108 is a particularly smooth number), but all these nines are just an auxiliary phenomenon.

Comment: I don't mean to offend your knowledge and research, but seriously, there is no point in looking for patterns of this low a level. I can find many such patterns everywhere. Hinduism is extremely wide, just taking a number and seeing it cropping up at a few places _is_ baseless. Again, I am not saying that @Mr_Green is wrong or something. I am adding why I don't think it makes sense.

Comment: @Mr_Green Also, in your link, the thing about number of breaths taken is utter nonsense. It appears to be correct to within an order of magnitude (I haven't double-checked), but that doesn't justify the numerological rubbish that the author has extracted from that.

Comment: My god, your second link is awful! What does baseball (26) or the diameter of the Earth in the arbitrary unit of miles (30) or Catholic practice (10) or fictitious Babylonian history (14) have to do with anything!?

Comment: @senshin haha..  didn't check it sorry. but please stick to my question that I am asking what is the exact significance of number 9? if there is none. then the answer should be simply "none".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numbers 18, 108, 1008, 10008 are all multiples of 9 which is a mystic number. All multiples of 9 added together ultimately become number 9. This can be verified (16x9=144; 1+4+4=9).
The mystic number 9 is arrived as follows:
The universe is constituted of the three factors - time, space and causation.
The universe is constituted of the three Gunas (ingredients) - sattva, rajas and tamas.
The universe is constituted of the three functions - creation, preservation and destruction.
This three times three making nine has made nine a mystic number. The number nine exhausts the definition of the phenomenal universe.

Twice nine or eighteen makes the Mahabharata scheme complete. 
The eighteen Parvas define in detail the career of man on earth.
The eighteen chapters in the Gita make Yoga philosophy complete.
The eighteen day war makes the warrior's exploits complete.
Eighteen are the divisions of the armies of the contending parties -Pandavas and Kauravas with one having seven and the other eleven divisions. Thus all the available human forces mobilized were eighteen in number.

The Mahabharata is thus an exposition of the human possibilities and achievements graded into eighteen, the first multiple of nine. The higher multiples of nine signify further ranging into divine regions.

REF:Swami Chidbhavananda in his commentary on the Gitas