# Significance of number 7 as per Vedas

Tags: vedas, numbers

As per Vedas what exactly is the significance of number 7. Reason am asking this is because we have:

- *Saptarishi* (7 Sages)
- 7 *Chakras*
- 7 Days
- 7 *Svara*
- 7 colors in rainbow (Indradhanush)
- 7 *pheras* during marriage

There are so many others as listed [here](http://bhargavasarma.blogspot.ca/2012/10/saptha-number-seven-7-symbolism-and.html).
Curious to understand the logic behind this.

Comment: numerology is a separate science. not part of vedas.

Comment: Vedas don't discuss the significance of numbers. Edit the question and tags. For example, see this question [Number 9 in Hindu mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/215/number-9-in-hindu-mythology).

Comment: Well my question wasn't from numerology point of view but like stated above we do have 7 chakras so this has to be something significant from vedic point of view, hence I wanted to understand.

Comment: I believe Hindu scriptures are based on the deepest contemplation of nature. Like you mentioned 7 colors, you will find 7 to be more frequent compared to other numbers in nature. Some examples are: 7 tunes in a harmony, 7 continents, 7 perfect pH neutrality between acid and base, 7 principle energy levels for electron orbits etc... etc...

Comment: I agree to what you just stated..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seven is significant because during the onset of creation, seven was the number of surrounding sheaths in the Yajna (sacrifice) in which Purusha himself was the offering. And, the number of such offerings (Samit) was also 21, a multiple of 7.

The relevant mantra from the Purusha Suktam is the following:

> **SaptAsyAsan paridhayas** (1)
>  **Trih sapta samidhah** kritAh (2)
>  DevA
>   yat yajnam tanvanA (3)
>  Abadhnan purusham pashum (4) ||
>
> **Meaning**
>
> The Gods, giving body to yajna (3), bound Purusha, the seer (4). **Seven were
>   the surrounding sheaths (paridhi) (1), Thrice seven** the prepared fuels
>   (samit) (2).
>
> **Rig Veda 10.90.15**

As per Rishi Aurobindo, the seven paridhis being talked about here are the seven planes of existence.

> **Three lower ones**
>
> Matter (anna), life-energy (prana) and mind.
>
> **Three higher ones:**
>
> Ananda (jana), conscious-force (tapa) and truth of existence (satya).
>
> The seventh plane is the link-world between the two triplets and is
>   called Mahas, the plane of Vijyana or Super-mind. The twenty-one fuels
>   are the three energies in each of the seven planes.

So, as we can see the number 7 and its multiple (21) had significant roles to play during the onset of creation itself. So, that's basically why it's important.